# Plural of 'rush hour'

Tags: idioms, grammatical-number

Can I use 'rush hours' in the sentence 'Can you sustain load during rush hours?'? Or should I say 'rush hour' in this context?

Comment: Plural sounds OK to me.  There are usually 2 "rush hours" per day. It might be good to specify whether you mean morning, evening, or both.

Comment: It was used in idiomatic meaning. 'Rush hours' for evening traffic peaks.  So 'rush hours' can be used. Thank you.

Comment: Use 'during a rush hour' instead. It is applicable to any moment. 'Rush hours' is fine though, but I suggest adding a dash such as 'rush-hours', to disable interpretation of rush as a verb.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest "rush hour periods" or "peak commute hours". The plural "rush hours" seems awkward.